What is a good free Win 11 program to write to dvd- or cd-rw?
I want to back-up my files to an optical disk. I haven't done anything like this in a while, so I don't know what's out there. Prefer free, of course, but could pay if necessary.
Thanks!

The free one is built right in.
You can use

File Explorer

Select all files you want to burn and send to DVD


Windows Media Player

Switch to library
Press on Burn



In both cases the drive must have a suitable DVD in it.
